# Implementing ResNet50 on 56x56x1 Input

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to implement ResNet50 with an input layer of shape (56,56,1) with 10 output classifications.

I instantiate the model as so

```
model = tf.keras.applications.resnet50.ResNet50(
    weights = None, #random
    input_shape = ( 56, 56, 1 ),
    classes = 10
)
```

I train the model, and feed it one of the training examples to see what it does. It seems like the output shape is not what I am expecting

```
a = model.predict(x_test_preprocess[15288])
print(a.shape)
```

> (56, 10)

Doing a bit of poking, it looks like the output layer shape makes sense

```
print(len(model.layers))
print(model.layers[176].input_shape)
print(model.layers[176].output_shape)
```

> 177

> (None, 2048)

> (None, 10)

So if the output_shape of the last layer is (None,10), why am I getting a tensor shape of (56, 10) for my prediction?

Am I handling color channels wrong? Am I allowed to simply give it a single channel input shape as I have or do I need to duplicate the greyscale over the RGB channels and build it with a (56,56,3) shape?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is input is not same as the input_shape. Model expects input to be `(None, 56, 56, 1)` but when you try to put x_test_preprocess[15288], your input shape will become `(56, 56, 1)`. When this happens keras automaticaly try to fit network with what it got, which will not produce corret results. You can do the following to fix this issue:

```py
a = model.predict(x_test_preprocess[15288].reshape([-1,56,56,1])
```